# Yehu punished for Yizre'el?

Tags: murder, melachim-kings-book-of, hosea-hoshea

Hoshea 1:3-5:

"So he went and married Gomer the daughter of Divlayim, and she conceived and bore him a son. HASHEM said to him," Call him Yizre'el; because in only a short time I will punish the house of Yehu for having shed blood at Yizre'el; I will put an end to the kingdom of the house of Yisra'el. When that day comes, I will break the bow of Yisra'el in the Yizre'el Valley."

HASHEM here is saying that He will punish Yehu for the bloodshed at Yizre'el. But didn't HASHEM Himself order Yehu to kill Achav's dinasty?

Melakhim Bet 9:6-8:

"This is what HASHEM the G-d of Yisra'el says: 'I have anointed you king over the people of HASHEM, over Yisra'el. You will attack the house of Achav your master, so that I can avenge the blood of my servants the prophets and of all the servants of HASHEM, blood shed by Izevel. The entire house of Achav will perish; I will cut off from Achav every male, whether a slave or free in Yisra'el..... "

So why would HASHEM punish Yehu for the bloodshed at Yizre'el if HASHEM Himself is the one who ordered Yehu to do that?

Answer (score 2):

[Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Hosea.1.4.2?lang=bi), [Radak](https://www.sefaria.org/Radak_on_Hosea.1.4.1?lang=bi) and [Metzudat David](https://www.sefaria.org/Metzudat_David_on_Hosea.1.4.1?lang=bi) to Hoshea' 1:4 all explain that Yehu was supposed to wipe out Achav and his house due to their sins of idolatory. Once Yehu and his descendants also began to serve idols, G-d no longer treated Yehu's killing of Achav's house as a meritorious act, but instead as shedding innocent blood.

[Malbim](https://www.sefaria.org/Malbim_on_Hosea.1.4.1?lang=bi) has a slightly different understanding of the verse, reading it as saying that G-d will punish Yehu in the same way as he punished Achav, owing to Yehu following Achav in engaging in idolatory.